# how to change design of VScode terminal when using `ls` for viewing files?

Tags: visual-studio-code, web, terminal, desktop

I am a beginner, thus like many, I have a fundamental question. I will appreciate it if you can help!

So, I am currently using VSCode from 2 places: (1) The desktop (For everything), and (2) The web (For CS50x).

When I use the `ls` command from the terminal to view the files/folders, the two places show them very differently. I love the web view and I want to change the desktop view to that.

IMAGE 1 (This is what I like)
[image: This is from the VSCode web]

IMAGE 2 (This is what I want to change)
[image: This is from the VSCode desktop]

So, any idea what can I do?

Comment: So I have now understood that it was about the Terminal shell (Pardon my amateur language). Since then I have installed the git bash and I think that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ✅ **here is the design of `Git Bash`'s terminal:**

[image]

### ❌ **here is the previous one `Powershell`:**

[image]

---

---

**why?**

every terminal has its own design, and vs code technically only integrates it inside the editor.

`PowerShell` is the default one.

---

**how?**

and also vscode can make you choose what terminal you like most to work with.

> click "+" icon and choose another terminal

[image]

in your case, you are using `powershell`, but if you use `bash` for example and you can get a similar design.

> by default it will open PowerShell, but I think you can configure in setting to make always open another terminal in vs code.

---

**but isn't 100% similar?**

if you want 100% equal you can try to install a new terminal on your own

 and then use it inside vscode

I've seen devs using Linux terminals on windows by installing it by themselves,

I think the ubuntu terminal is the easiest to install among all the Linux terminals

(but you can follow a tutorial on youtube if you are interested in it)

> but for me git bash's terminal is fine :)
>
>  `ls` is 100% accurate design in git bash, so it isn't necessary to complexity, just make it simple
>
> I also tested some terminal commands (cd, ls, git commit, etc...) and they are working fine (similar to Powershell)